# Ramachandran Plot Trajectories

Tags: python

I have plotted the Ramachandran Plot and got several dots which are clustered together. Now I want to make a trajectory file in python of a particular cluster from a range of (-100 to -10) phi angle and (-50 to -200) psi angle. Can someone help me out as to how should I go about it?